# Should I use foreach vs LINQ for sorting and initializing objects in a Dictionary?

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary, foreach

I have a `IDictionary<string,dynamic>` like so

```
IDictionary<string, dynamic> protoTemplate;
```

Within the dictionary, I have a variety of objects that I have to sort and use to initialize new objects. I can either do it like this with a `foreach` loop:

```
var entries = new IDictionary<string, ConfigurationEntry>();
foreach (var value in protoTemplate["keys"]){
       entries.Add(value.Key, new ConfigurationEntry(value.Value["description"], value.Value["protection"], value.Value["type"], value.Key, value.Value["default"]));
}
```

or alternatively I could use LINQ queries and do it this way.

```
IDictionary<string, ConfigurationEntry> entries = (from keys in (IDictionary<object, object>)protoTemplate["keys"] select keys)
        .ToDictionary(value => (string)value.Key, value => ((IDictionary<object, object>)value.Value)
        .ToDictionary(entry => (string)entry.Key, entry => (dynamic)entry.Value))
        .ToDictionary(value => value.Key, value => new ConfigurationEntry(value.Value["description"], value.Value["protection"], value.Value["type"], value.Key, value.Value["default"]));
```

My dillema is whether to use the `foreach` loop or LINQ to sort my dictionary. Since my dictionary is dynamic, I have to cast the object before I can use a LINQ query on it, and my LINQ solution seems less readable than the `foreach` loop. `protoTemplate` comes from deserialized YAML, and all items in a collection are parsed as `object`s and have to be converted to the correct type. Given that, is there any advantage to using LINQ in this case, over looping over the items in the dictionary?

Comment: It seems like you want two things at once - performant(?) code and readable code. I'd code to performance based practice first then make it more readable. You provided a generic example, is there a generic type you can create to make life easier?

Comment: As @wahwahwah asked, what matters to you? Do you care about your code having better performance or being readable? Simply asking "which is better" is a bit irrelevant as it has a really broad scope. You have to narrow it down.

Comment: I don't see a single "sort" or "order by" anywhere in this code. What do you mean by using "LINQ to sort my dictionary"? As near as I can tell, you're just enumerating a `Dictionary<string, IDictionary<object, object>>`, and using the key-value-pairs from the value dictionaries to populate the `ConfigurationEntry` instances. I find the LINQ version _obfuscated_ as compared to the imperative version, and it doesn't look as performant either (it seems to be doing a lot of extra work compared to the imperative version). So IMHO here the clear winner is your first example.